# Understanding odd results when paginating double outerjoins

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with Flask and SQLAlchemy and I stumble on behavior I do not understand. When I build a query with `.outerjoin()` and `.paginate()` it all works well until today when I created a query with double `outerjoin` related from one another like on the simplified example code bellow (`db` is reference to SQLAlchemy). Class `First` has one-to-many relation with `Second` and `Second` is one-to-one with `Third`.

For testing purpose I have prepared three search queries. First two `search_1` and `search_2` works well all the time. But `search_3` works only until there are two `Second` records related to the same `First` record. When there is more than one `Second` related to `First` then query returns mostly lower number of records (but not as low as when using .join instead of .outerjoin) and in some cases even higher then the number of records in `First` table. What's strange number of records is changing even when using different sorting order (always by columns of `First` model).

```py
class First(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'first'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_create = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    date_update = db.Column(db.DateTime)


class Second(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'second'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('first.id'))
    third_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('third.id'))


class Third(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'third'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_create = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


# prepare base query to reuse later
outer_base = First.query \
    .outerjoin(Second, Second.first_id == First.id) \
    .outerjoin(Third, Third.id == Second.third_id) \
    .order_by(First.id.asc())

# works well
search_1 = First.query.order_by(First.id.asc()).paginate(1, 10, False)

# works well
search_2 = outer_base.all()

# odd as hell...
search_3 = outer_base.paginate(1, 10, False)
```

I just want to be able to filter `First` records by value from `Third` if there is any relation created with the use of `Second` table. Can anyone please explain me what am I missing? Maybe the double outerjoin can be achieved differently to work with pagination?